# Is it possible for two seperate instances of Memcached to communicate with each other?

Tags: memcached

I have got two applications running, both of them have a dedicated instance of the Memcached server each.

Is it possible that these two separate instances of Memcached talk to each other ?? If we delete a key on one instance of Memcached

I need to delete the key on the other instance of Memcached? is that possible ??

Answer (score 2):

No. Memcached does not have that kind of functionality. It is purely a key/value store. You will need your application to do this explicitly.

Comment: Thanks , any idea , how to deal with this situation ??

Comment: You need to expand your question to explain why you have 2 memcached servers, why the same key appears in both, are the values the same (for a given key). Is possible to combine the 2 servers into one so that there is only one key/value pair?

Comment: Also, DON'T change this question. Ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The memcached client should do this transparently. If you store a key/value pair it's stored on one or more servers via the client. The same with deletion. Memcached servers don't know about each other.

Answer (score 0):

http://memcached.org/about  seems to suggest you can ...

https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgramming

for more info